# best way to share QR code for TOTP Authentication

Tags: one-time-password, google-authenticator

I'm currently working on a server based implementation of TOTP in order to reinforce the authentication of the user by using an OTP code.
But I'm wondering how to share for the first time the QR Code (or the secret key) with the end user ? for sure the email is not the preferable choice but as I'll not have a physical contact with the end users it will be difficult to share the QR Code in another way...

another question related to TOTP if the end user is losing its mobile phone to generate its code, do I permit the end user to generate a new QR Code ? but in that case how can I share it ? (in fact this is the same question....)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to provide the QR code to the users you could use a portal that is externally accessible, but is itself protected by factors other than the one you are delivering.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to keep your server secure you should not be sharing the QR Code / OTP Setup Code via any means, but that is not very usable.

One option is to disable two factor while the user logs in, then re-enable and have the user set it up - this is the most secure way but not very manageable.

Another option is to share the QR code with the user via a secure messaging protocol and then requiring the user to reset their password and re-setup Two Factor.

What OS are you running on your server and is this for SSH access?

Comment: I'm using a Linux server and yes this is for user authentication on an intranet web app